# Comparison of discrete logarithms.

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

**Additive discrete logarithm**:

In $\Bbb Z_n^+$ we have to find $z$ in $zg=h\bmod n$ where $g$ generates $\Bbb Z_n^+$. $z$ is unique upto $z \bmod n$.

**Multiplicative discrete logarithm**:

In a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n^\times$ we have to find $z$ in $g^z=h\bmod p$ where $g$ generates $\Bbb Z_n^\times$. $z$ is unique upto $z \bmod n-1$.

**Elliptic curve discrete logarithm**:

In Elliptic curve group of points $E(\Bbb Z_n)$ where $n$ is an integer (may be composite) we have to find $z$ in $zG=H$ where $G$ generates $E(\Bbb Z_n)$. Is $z$ is unique up to $z \bmod n-1$?

Comment: The discrete logarithm is always *unique modulo the order of the base*. So the additive discrete logarithm is unique modulo $n$. The logarithm in $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$ is unique modulo $\phi(n)$ (if $n$ is prime, then $\phi(n)=n-1$), and the EC discrete logarithm is unique modulo the order of $G$. If $G$, indeed, generates the group $E(\Bbb{Z}_n)$ (that group is not always cyclic, so such a point $G$ may not exist), then the discrete logarithm is unique modulo $|E(\Bbb{Z}_n)|$, i.e. modulo the number of points on the elliptic curve.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen where do you learn about these subtleties for elliptic curve cryptography?

Comment: Depends. If you have a strong enough background in basic structures of abstract algebra, then this particular question becomes relatively easy - familiarity with cyclic groups is enough. Some properties of Elliptic curves that come to the fore in EC crypto algorithms are graduate level material. For background in algebra any textbook will probably do. For basic EC crypto I once (co-)ran a seminar using Menezes' book. I learned a lot from Silvermann, but that's more hardcore. After reviewing abstract algebra basics, you could start with Menezes. May be something better is out there? IANACryppie

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen **(1)** What if $G$ does not generate $|E(\Bbb Z_n)|$ or $E(\Bbb Z_n)$ is not cyclic? We do not use those curves? **(2)** Aren't all cyclic groups of same order isomorphic to each other? So is ECDLP same as DLP for cyclic groups if we know the isomorphism?

Comment: (1) IIRC the groups of the curves $E$ that make it to a standard are cyclic more often than not, so you're right we don't use such curves. (2) Yes. But for DLPs to be the same we need the isomorphisms to be efficiently computable **in both directions**. One direction here is efficient (calculation of $zG$) but the inverse is not, and that's the catch.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen On **(2)** this is what I think supposing $|E(\Bbb Z_n)| = p$ a prime then **(a)** for every primitive root of unity (generator) of $\Bbb Z_p$ there should be a point $G$ in $E(\Bbb Z_n)$ that generates $E(\Bbb Z_n)$ and vice versa. **(b)** there should be an isomorphism map $f:\Bbb Z_p\rightarrow E(\Bbb Z_n)$. Then are $f$ and $f^{-1}$ easily computable and do they give polynomial time reduction between the two so that DLP reduces to ECDLP and vice versa in polynomial time? If so then they should be considered equivalent correct?

Comment: No. Because computing the inverse $f^{-1}$ is equivalent to solving the ECDLP. It is not easily computable. Not even in the case of the isomorphism $f:(\Bbb{Z}_{p-1},+)\to(\Bbb{Z}_p^*,\cdot)$.